# How to use HTML5 file api to dynamically attach an image for file upload, base64

Tags: javascript, html, image, file-upload, base64

I need to dynamically add a picture to the input field files (HTML5 file api). It must be added using some base64 string for this. I found this way to add files to the input field, but I want to understand if it is possible to do the same for images using base64 encoding of this image.

```js
const dT = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer(); 
dT.items.add(new File(['foo'], 'programmatically_created.txt'));
inp.files = dT.files;
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
```

Comment: An img tag src can be base64 string. Since src can be changed via javascript, likewise you can define it to some base64 string

Comment: @GetSet I thought about it too. But how to attach this picture to the input field?

Comment: Helen it appears you want the HTML5 file api

Comment: @GetSet Yes you are right

Comment: Im not too versed with that API. Perhaps you could reword your question for better responses from the community to include those keywords. "How to use HTML5 file api to dynamically attach an image for file upload, base64" for example

Comment: I upvoted in hopes this gets an answer from someone knowledgeable

Comment: Close and repost in the morning. This thread will be lost